# Java Thread, change value in thread from main

Tags: java, multithreading

With the thread class defined below, if the main calls the thread by:

```
     Thread foo = new aThread1();
     foo.start();
```

Is it possible to change the value of xxx from the calling class?  It was simple to change variables while in the thread OF the main class, but I can't seem to go the other way.

```
class aThread1 extends Thread {
volatile static int xxx = 1;
public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Current value: " + xxx);
    }
 }
```

Comment: From where do you want to change the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the field as `public`

```
public volatile static int xxx = 1;
```

And from any code:

```
aThread1.xxx = 2;
```

Comment: But foo is the reference to the thread, is it not?  How would this example work, for instance, if two threads were created from that class (so now we have foo and bar both creating new threads from aThread1).

Comment: @the-lists Change the field to non-static, then you can call `((aThread1)foo).xxx = 2;` or better yet, just declare foo as `aThread foo = new aThread();`

Comment: Thanks.  Exactly what I was after.  A bit of a java n00b here.  Just playing around with some code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [AtomicInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and pass it as a reference to the thread (i.e. aThread1) from main. You also need to handle the InterruptedException [properly](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=276&thread=161312).